# jQuery, CSS, -webkit-transform: NO animation

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, transform, webkit-transform

I am using code to change the -webkit-transform property of an element. However, I want to do this WITHOUT the transition animation playing: e.g. I want to go from transformX(-300px) to transformX(0) without a slide in-between. This is the code I have so far, but it is ineffective. I have to have "list-style-type" set to none otherwise the step function will not run.

```
$("#slider > ul").animate({"list-style-type": "none"}, {step: 
function(now, fx) {
    $(this).css('-webkit-transform', 'translateX(0)')
} 
});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Just do

```
$("#slider > ul").css('-webkit-transform', 'translateX(0)');
```